# Video JS controls with AJAX call

Tags: php, ajax, html5-video

Good day,

I am attempting to create a webpage that  when the user clicks something (triggered by a javascript onClick) call, an ajax request is sent to the server which triggers a php file to generate html to be assigned to the .innerHTML of a div.

Everything works fine except that the video does not have the controls (like the play button, fullscreen, etc)

Without the AJAX call, a simple hard coded version displays the video just fine with the controls, so something with the AJAX. I am using the Video JS player and to my knowledge the code doesn't have any scripts that need to execute.

Here is my php code...

```
<?php

    echo '<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="720" height="528" data-setup=\'{"controls":true}\'><source src="videos/'.$_GET["fn"].'" type=\'video/ogg\'/></video>';

?>
```

I believe it has something to do with the fact that javascript doesn't execute on an AJAX call, but I don't know for sure...

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like whatever code is used by Video JS is only executed on page load, and you are adding the player after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VideoJS checks for video tags on pageload, when your AJAX result markup is not loaded yet. You need to manually initialise VideoJS after your video call has returned.

```
var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");
```

See VideoJS API documentation for details: http://videojs.com/docs/api/

Comment: Wow! That immediately fixed my problem! I added that line to the initial page load (not in the ajax section) and everything works just great now! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I am a liar. Apparently when I went to go test the change, I used Firefox (whos default video player has a fullscreen option) where as originally when I was having problems, I was using Google chrome which does not have a default full screen control on their video player. So long story short, I appreciate your help, but apparently it didn't do the job.

Comment: What happens if you call the function *after* your ajax result has beed added to the DOM, as I suggested?